# Accessing the quantile regression estimates values from the rq function

Tags: r, regression, quantreg

I am performing a quantile regression as following:

```
library(quantreg) #quantile regression framework

#function to perform quantile regression with bootstrap confidence intervals
rq_bootstrap <- function(data, n_bootstrap = 1000) {
  rq_model <- summary(
    rq(julian_day ~ year_centered, data = data, tau = 1:99 / 100),
    se = "boot",
    bsmethod = "xy",
    R = n_bootstrap,
    level = 0.95
  )
  plot(rq_model, mfrow = c(1, 2))
  coef_df <- as.data.frame(sapply(rq_model, function(x) c(tau = x$tau, x$coefficients[-1, ])))
  return(list(model_summary = rq_model, coefficients = coef_df))
}

#apply the function
rq_results_lat1 <- rq_bootstrap(lat1)
```

The resulting plot is correct. However, I would like to access to the estimates values and the values of their bootstrap confidence interval, but I do not manage to.

Here is a sample of my data frame for reproductibility:

```
> dput(lat1[sample(nrow(lat1), 50),])
structure(list(date = structure(c(5567, 14294, 12820, 16167, 
17629, 14327, 16452, 16130, 18664, 13913, 13243, 15759, 12507, 
11049, 15410, 11342, 12821, 16147, 13240, 18645, 17979, 11706, 
17607, 17615, 16528, 16131, 13562, 18349, 13221, 14290, 15068, 
16507, 15059, 14997, 14283, 9931, 3677, 15421, 12151, 13591, 
13920, 16548, 16123, 18294, 13596, 17186, 12862, 6690, 13218, 
13252), class = "Date"), lat = c(57, 56, 57, 59, 58, 59, 56, 
59, 56, 56, 59, 57, 56, 57, 59, 55, 56, 56, 59, 59, 59, 56, 57, 
57, 58, 56, 58, 55, 57, 56, 58, 59, 58, 58, 56, 58, 58, 58, 56, 
57, 57, 55, 59, 56, 56, 55, 57, 59, 59, 59), long = c(11, 12, 
12, 17, 11, 15, 12, 18, 12, 16, 14, 11, 16, 11, 15, 12, 16, 16, 
18, 16, 17, 12, 13, 12, 13, 12, 12, 13, 11, 16, 14, 17, 12, 14, 
16, 14, 11, 17, 16, 18, 12, 14, 16, 12, 12, 12, 13, 16, 17, 15
), julian_day = c(89, 50, 37, 97, 98, 83, 17, 60, 37, 35, 95, 
54, 90, 93, 71, 20, 38, 77, 92, 18, 83, 19, 76, 84, 93, 61, 49, 
88, 73, 46, 94, 72, 85, 23, 39, 70, 26, 82, 99, 78, 42, 113, 
53, 33, 83, 20, 79, 117, 70, 104), year = c("1985", "2009", "2005", 
"2014", "2018", "2009", "2015", "2014", "2021", "2008", "2006", 
"2013", "2004", "2000", "2012", "2001", "2005", "2014", "2006", 
"2021", "2019", "2002", "2018", "2018", "2015", "2014", "2007", 
"2020", "2006", "2009", "2011", "2015", "2011", "2011", "2009", 
"1997", "1980", "2012", "2003", "2007", "2008", "2015", "2014", 
"2020", "2007", "2017", "2005", "1988", "2006", "2006"), decade = c("1980-1989", 
"2000-2009", "2000-2009", "2010-2019", "2010-2019", "2000-2009", 
"2010-2019", "2010-2019", "2020-2029", "2000-2009", "2000-2009", 
"2010-2019", "2000-2009", "2000-2009", "2010-2019", "2000-2009", 
"2000-2009", "2010-2019", "2000-2009", "2020-2029", "2010-2019", 
"2000-2009", "2010-2019", "2010-2019", "2010-2019", "2010-2019", 
"2000-2009", "2020-2029", "2000-2009", "2000-2009", "2010-2019", 
"2010-2019", "2010-2019", "2010-2019", "2000-2009", "1990-1999", 
"1980-1989", "2010-2019", "2000-2009", "2000-2009", "2000-2009", 
"2010-2019", "2010-2019", "2020-2029", "2000-2009", "2010-2019", 
"2000-2009", "1980-1989", "2000-2009", "2000-2009"), time = c(13L, 
15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 
16L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 
17L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 13L, 15L, 15L), lat_grouped = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), year_centered = structure(c(85, 109, 105, 
114, 118, 109, 115, 114, 121, 108, 106, 113, 104, 100, 112, 101, 
105, 114, 106, 121, 119, 102, 118, 118, 115, 114, 107, 120, 106, 
109, 111, 115, 111, 111, 109, 97, 80, 112, 103, 107, 108, 115, 
114, 120, 107, 117, 105, 88, 106, 106), class = "AsIs")), row.names = c(3378L, 
21344L, 11753L, 33172L, 42002L, 22010L, 33453L, 31852L, 49389L, 
17982L, 15167L, 29657L, 11059L, 7655L, 27224L, 7730L, 11784L, 
32491L, 14955L, 48899L, 44025L, 8367L, 40663L, 41022L, 35232L, 
31932L, 16540L, 47318L, 13830L, 21255L, 26321L, 34488L, 25776L, 
25064L, 21134L, 6545L, 2085L, 27476L, 9846L, 17134L, 18082L, 
35808L, 31695L, 45590L, 17310L, 37493L, 12220L, 4371L, 13731L, 
15875L), class = "data.frame")

> head(lat1)
          date lat long julian_day year    decade time lat_grouped year_centered
592 1970-01-18  57   12         18 1970 1970-1979   12           1            70
593 1970-01-18  57   18         18 1970 1970-1979   12           1            70
594 1970-01-18  56   12         18 1970 1970-1979   12           1            70
595 1970-01-18  57   18         18 1970 1970-1979   12           1            70
596 1970-01-19  56   16         19 1970 1970-1979   12           1            70
597 1970-01-23  56   12         23 1970 1970-1979   12           1            70
```

I would be glad if someone knows how to extract the researched values.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You already have the estimates and standard errors for each centile in your result. Perhaps you are looking for them in a long-format data frame, in which case `t(rq_results_lat1$coefficients)` will give you a data frame with 100 rows and 5 columns: one column for the centile (tau), one for the estimate and one for the standard error (plus a t value and p value)

Comment: thank you for your answer @AllanCameron. My main concern is that in `t(rq_results_lat1$coefficients)` I have the std error, but I do not have the lower bound and upper bound of the bootstrap CI generated. But they must be stored somewhere, as the plot shows in grey the CI - I just do not find how to access them (e.g. in a long-format data frame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data are already there in the output, but you probably need to reshape it into a format with estimates and upper / lower confidence intervals. The confidence intervals can be calculated, since they are simply the fit +/- 1.96 standard errors.

The manipulation is probably a bit easier using tidyverse functions:

```r
library(quantreg) 
library(tidyverse)

rq_bootstrap <- function(data, n_bootstrap = 1000) {
  suppressWarnings(
    rq(julian_day ~ year_centered, data = data, tau = 1:99 / 100)
    ) %>%
    summary(se = "boot", bsmethod = "xy", R = n_bootstrap, level = 0.95) %>%
    map_df(function(x) {
      coef(x) |>
        as.data.frame() |>
        cbind(variable = rownames(coef(x)), tau = x$tau)
    }) %>%
    bind_rows() %>%
    mutate(lower = Value - `Std. Error` * 1.96, 
           upper = Value + `Std. Error` * 1.96) %>%
    select(variable, tau, Value, lower, upper) %>%
    as_tibble()
}
```

Now if we run our function, we get a nicer result:

```r
rq_results_lat1 <- rq_bootstrap(lat1)

rq_results_lat1
#> # A tibble: 198 x 5
#>    variable        tau   Value   lower   upper
#>    <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 (Intercept)    0.01 34.7    -76.2   146.   
#>  2 year_centered  0.01 -0.154   -1.14    0.836
#>  3 (Intercept)    0.02 34.7    -54.6   124.   
#>  4 year_centered  0.02 -0.154   -0.949   0.641
#>  5 (Intercept)    0.03 34.7    -81.1   150.   
#>  6 year_centered  0.03 -0.154   -1.19    0.885
#>  7 (Intercept)    0.04 24.4    -92.0   141.   
#>  8 year_centered  0.04 -0.0526  -1.09    0.985
#>  9 (Intercept)    0.05 30.1    -94.5   155.   
#> 10 year_centered  0.05 -0.100   -1.22    1.02 
#> # ... with 188 more rows
```

And to show this is the expected output, let's plot this using `ggplot`

```r
ggplot(rq_results_lat1, aes(tau, Value)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.3) +
  ggh4x::geom_pointpath(size = 1) +
  facet_wrap(.~variable, scale = 'free_y') +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        panel.spacing = unit(1, "cm"))
```

[image]

This is identical to the base R plot obtained with `plot(rq_model)`, though when you plot the summary you need to specify the confidence level. We can check the output of the above code is correct by doing:

```r
plot(rq_model, mfrow = c(1, 2), level = 0.95)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Yes indeed, it is in the output as I can plot it, but the structure of it makes it hard to access to the numerical values. and I did not find any direct way so far. Thank you very much for providing a solution. I'll ask just one more precision, isn't the fit +/- 1.96 standard errors valuable only if we have a normal distribution?

Comment: "the confidence intervals seem to be calculated from the covariance matrix - but I could show you it if you like" -> Yes I would if you are able to, please! if I understand you properly,  1.96 * se is an approximate, but you are able to obtain the true values?

Comment: @Recology actually, now that I look into it, when you do `plot(rq_model)`, this invokes `quantreg:::plot.summary.rqs`, and this calculates the confidence intervals using `qnorm(1 - (1 - level)/2)`. When `level = 0.95`, this _does_ turn out to be 1.96 (the bootstrap estimates will follow the central limit theorem, so that's where the normal distribution comes in). It looks as though when you plot the model summary, it defaults to level = 0.9, which is why the scales of the two plots looks a little different. My values are the correct ones - I will update the answer to show this.

Comment: Oh right, I understand better now. "It looks as though when you plot the model summary, it defaults to level = 0.9, which is why the scales of the two plots looks a little different." -> This is strange though, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Recology but you can adjust this - see my update.